# Creating Objects (it works, but is this just a var or an object) - js

Tags: javascript, object

```
 var firstExample = Object.create(potentialEnergy) 
    firstExample.height = 200
    firstExample.mass = 85

var secondExample = Object.create(potentialEnergy)
    secondExample.height = 150
    secondExample.mass = 100


var thirdExample = Object.create(potentialEnergy)
    thirdExample.height = 250
    thirdExample.mass = 75


// object method
var potentialEnergy = {
    getPE: function () {
        const potential = this.mass * this.height * 9.8
        return potential
    }
}

console.log(firstExample.getPE())
console.log(secondExample.getPE())
console.log(thirdExample.getPE())
```

question: In my first attempt I created three objects w/ properties of mass and height using the given notation (var firstExample = {}, and the properties below)and then (seperate line of code) I attempted to link the potential energy method with the firstExample object via --> 
var firstExample = Object.create(potentialEnergy) and this returned NaN,

I then did Object.create(potentialEnergy) when I created all three objects and the program worked,

my question is are firstExample (and second/third) being made into objects or just variables, because I am currently not using either of the methods I was taught(var firstExample = {} , or open brackets {with the properties within}), and if they are being made into objects then does "Object.create" both link the potentialEnergy method with firstExample and* make firstExample into an object?

Comment: You have to move the declaration of `potentialEnergy` before you try to use it. https://jsfiddle.net/9703zbqo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the declaration's order:

So, it will be:

```
// object method
var potentialEnergy = {
    getPE: function () {
        const potential = this.mass * this.height * 9.8
        return potential
    }
}

var firstExample = Object.create(potentialEnergy) 
    firstExample.height = 200
    firstExample.mass = 85

var secondExample = Object.create(potentialEnergy)
    secondExample.height = 150
    secondExample.mass = 100


var thirdExample = Object.create(potentialEnergy)
    thirdExample.height = 250
    thirdExample.mass = 75

console.log(firstExample.getPE())
console.log(secondExample.getPE())
console.log(thirdExample.getPE())
```